# Creating JavaScript objects inside of a for loop and using the unique objects in a different for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I've been working on an automated GUI test using JavaScript code. I had been going back through this overall test and optimizing some of the code. For example, I had a function to input values into all the fields of a window that looks more or less like this:

| Row | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 | Field 6 | Field 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Originally the input function looked like this: `inputRowValues(row, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7);` This was rather clunky and took up a lot of space and wasn't as neat as editting the function to take in a single object that had the fields as property values. Now the function looked something like this: `inputRowValues(rowObject);` where `rowObject` was defined like this:

```
let rowObject = 
{
    field1: someValue,
    field2: someValue,
    field3: someValue,
    field4: someValue,
    field5: someValue,
    field6: someValue,
    field7: someValue
};
```

This worked beautifully until I got to the section testing one particular requirement that says that when you enter values into a window, you can close the window and reopen it and the values are still there. Originally I did this by creating a set of arrays that contained 10 random values for each field using a function (`createVarArray`) where parameter 1 and 2 are the min and max values for random numbers, parameter 3 is the number of items to put in the array, and parameter 4 is an optional parameter for a base other than 10.

```
// Generate random values for fields
var
    field1 = createVarArray(1, 2, 10),
    field2 = createVarArray(0, 1, 10),
    field3 = createVarArray(0, 77777, 10, 8),
    field4 = constantValue,
    field5 = createVarArray(0, 77777, 10, 8),
    field6 = createVarArray(0, 31, 10),
    field7 = createVarArray(0, 7, 10)
;
    
// Boolean values to randomly enter optional fields
var
    field3Bool = createVarArray(0, 1, 10),
    field5Bool = createVarArray(0, 1, 10),
    field6Bool = createVarArray(0, 1, 10),
    field7Bool = createVarArray(0, 1, 10)
;
```

Then I enter the values using the `inputRowValues()` function and using the fieldBool arrays to randomly leave some fields blank that are optional.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (field3Bool[i] === 0) field3[i] = "";
    if (field5Bool[i] === 0) field5[i] = "";
    
    if (field6Bool[i] === 0)
    {
        field6[i] = "";
        field7[i] = "";
    }
    else if (field6Bool[i] === 1 && field7Bool[i] === 0)
    {
        field7[i] = "";
    }
    
    // Input values into fields
    inputRowValues(i+1, field1[i], field2[i], field3[i], field4, field5[i], field6[i], field7[i]);
}
```

I then have to exit the for loop, "save the values" by clicking a "done" button, close the window and then reopen it.

```
clickDone();
clickX();
openWindow();
```

Because of this step, I have to verify that the field values have been saved correctly in a seperate for loop. If I wanted to create a `rowObject` object in the for loop there wouldn't be a way to access those values again for the next for loop. The only way I can think of doing it would be to create 10 different objects.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // These fields end up padding numbers that are less than 5 digits long with 0s in front so I add the padding for verification.
    if (field3[i] !== "") field3[i] = math.pad(field3[i], 5);
    if (field5[i] !== "") field5[i] = math.pad(field5[i], 5);
    
    // Verify correct values are saved in all fields
    verifyAllFields(i+1, field1[i], field2[i], field3[i], field4, field5[i], field6[i], field7[i]);
}
```

I cannot think of an efficient means of accomplishing this. Every solution I've thought of requires creating the 10 different filter objects and then doing 10 different input functions and 10 different verification functions which seems to be going backwards if my intent was to optimize code.

I know that this was a lot of code but hopefully I didn't loose you along the way.

Answer (score 0):

### Managing Data

Okay, so this is a problem called State Management. There's a lot of libraries out there to make this easier. Redux (with the Redux Toolkit) and Mobx to name two. I personally prefer the Redux approach.

Each "Row" can be part of [an entity adapter](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter), which is easy to serialize.

But the long and short of it is that you want to have a global, centralized data source to store and update your data. You want to have reasonable defaults (empty fields, 0, false, etc), and you want it to be serializable. It's only serializable if it is consistent. It's easier to serialize if the stuff operating on the data is not responsible for managing storage of it (IE: Global store of data).

If you choose to use a state management library, you want to treat each row as an entity. Each entity is added to the Entity Adapter with a unique id (row number is a valid id).

You fire an action to add to it, and use a selector to draw data from it. If you want to save it, you persist it to local storage or a file. If you want to load it, you check a file / local storage and use that as the initial state. If no data is present, you use a valid "empty" default. (`[]` for example)

---

### Verifying Data

You have two options. Roll your own, use a library, or both. I personally use libraries because validation is a solved problem generally speaking.

[schema-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schema-validator) is an example of a library that does it for you.

[validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) is an example of a library that gives you standardized validation functions. (is number, is email, etc).

My favorite approach to validating data in a roll-your-own fashion is to register an array of functions that check *only one* property each. `validateField1`, `validateField2`, etc. Each of these accept a `row`, and the only thing they look at is the property they are responsible for. You run through each of these validators in a for loop. You can either run through *all* validators and report all errors, or you can exit the moment one of them fails.

My favorite approach to validating data in an easy fashion is to use [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator).